# Wrong Character Ordering of Unicode Font in PDF

Tags: pdf, fonts, wkhtmltopdf

I have a PDF file containing some Burmese text in it. The PDF is generated with wkhtmltopdf with embedded fonts (Myanmar Census 3 [Pyidaungsu] for the Burmese text).

Some of the Burmese text is displayed correctly, while others are not: some characters are displayed in the wrong order.

However, when I copy the text from the PDF over to another program, it looks correct (indicating that the Unicode mapping was embedded correctly in the PDF).

Any pointers as to why the rendering of the font is out of order (in Burmese or any other language)?

Versions tried:
- wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 and 0.9.9.1
- ghostscript 9.15
- OS: Mac OSX and Linux

Comment: Have you tried an other PDF reader? What reader do you use?

Comment: I've tried Preview on Mac and Acrobat Reader on Windows. Printing the PDF gives the same result (wrong ordering).